# How can I safely read Log4j logs while another thread is logging at the same time?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, log4j

If I have multiple threads that use log4j to write to a single log file, and I want another thread to read it back out, is there a way to safely read(line by line) those logs such that I always read a full line?

EDIT:
Reason for this is I need to upload all logs to a central location and it might be logs that are days old or those that are just being written

Comment: According to [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#a1.7) it is thread-safe as-is - are you having any specific problems?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to roll the files and then read them after they are rolled?  Do you really need real-time monitoring of the logs?  If you do, how about writing your own appender that records them and then delegates to the log-writer so you can get the lines as they are logged.

Comment: @Gray: Reason for this is I need to upload all logs to a central location and it might be logs that are days old or those that are just being written

Comment: @Pescis: Does log4j have a thread safe way to read logs that have been written previously?

Comment: What we do is we have our own appenders that force the logs to roll at a predefined interval to be uploaded to a central location -- even if there is only one line since the last roll.

Comment: @Gray: Right now I roll the log file daily so that there won't be many files and the logs on the machine can be found based on the date. But that also means that the latest log file that I can upload is 1 day ago, is there no way to upload the latest log in real time?

Comment: We roll every 5 minutes because we're going to merge the logs later on the main box.  So when the appender fires we upload the log.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a read write lock.

Read locks can be held by multiple users if there is no one writing to the file, but a write lock can only be held by 1 thread at a time no matter what.

Just make sure that as your writing thread is done writing, it releases the readwritelock to allow the reading threads to read. Likewise, always release the read lock when the reader are done reading so log4j can continue to write

Check out

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html

However, coming to think of it, what is your purpose for this? If you simply want to monitor your logs, you should use a different solution rather than having a monitor thread within the same application. Seems to not make sense. If the data is available within the application / service, why pass it off to a file and read it right back in?

Comment: Does log4j use file locking?

Comment: i believe log4j does use file locking. This is why you can log to a single file safely across multiple threads.

Comment: @75inchpianist: But synchronization across multiple threads could also be done using mutexes, semaphores, etc, not necessarily file locking no?

Comment: yes. however, for your purposes a readwritelock might make more sense as the read locks will allow multiple threads to read at the same time. if you use mutexes, only one thread gets access to the file no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

It is going to be a pain if you need to implement what you are doing, especially you have to deal with file rolling.

For your specific requirement, there are better choices:

1. If the location you are going to be backed up can be directly written (i.e. mounted in your file system), it is better to simply set your file rolling to write to that backup directory; or
2. Make use of log management tools like Splunk to monitor and manage your log files (so that you don't even need to copy to that backup directory); or
3. Even you need to do the backup all by yourself, you don't need to (and have no reason to) do it in a separate thread.  Trying to write a shell script monitoring your log directory, and make use of tools like rsync or write similar logic by yourself, to do the upload only for files that are not matching in local and remote location.